# Dependency injection just for testing or production?

Tags: dependency-injection

Are dependency injection frameworks used just for testing or is it used in production code?  Seems once you start using a framework like ninject, you would not want to reverse everything out.  Also, is there a performance hit to using something like ninject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency Injection is an architecture pattern, not a testing one. So it is intended to be used when building production code. In fact, a really good framework introduces really tiny overhead if any. Can't say for sure if ninject or unity are like so, I used to implement my own.

Possible real downsides of DI are mostly around coding process, not production performance. One that should be probably mentioned: when using DI you lose an ability to walk through the code with 'Go to Definition' - it always brings you to interface which is pretty logical but still unusable.

Comment: Instead of 'go to definition', install ReSharper and press ctrl-alt-b.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely use DI in a production environment.  In a testing environment it is ok to just wire things up for the purposes of the test, indeed, if you are using mock objects, you might *have* to wire the classes up yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use it for everything! Why reverse it out? The performance hit for a quality framework should only happen on start up. Plus there might be a minor penalty until the VM can inline the extra layers. Either way you see a decrease in bugs and an increase in developer productivity.

DI is especially nice for production. In our software, we use the exact same configuration in production as we do in tests.

When the tests are run, the test configuration just flags certain services as being mocked out. This means that the test configuration is:

1. list out mocked out services
2. specify return values for the various method calls on the mocked out service methods.

Test Benefits:

1. No config differences between production and test means no possibility of a latent config dependent bug
2. Services are injected in to the Test class as well.
3. Test configuration is trivial (only needed really for cases where services are mocked out)
4. Test configuration is always same as production. ( easier to maintain )
5. Service initialization is never manual and hacked together.

Production Benefits:

1. Clean start up code - no hard coded dependencies
2. Circular dependencies are not an issue.
3. Ability to "turn off" a local copy of a service and route the requests to a different box. ( Used for background batch tasks )